# MongoDB Index on columns (A,B) smaller than index on just A

Tags: mongodb

I'm seeing a strange effect in MongoDB, and I was hoping someone can help me explain it.

As the title says, for the same collection, index

`db.my_collection.createIndex({"arrayField.subfield1": 1, "arrayField.subfield2": 1});`

is *smaller* than index

`db.my_collection.createIndex({"arrayField.subfield1": 1});`

Which I find very strange.

Sidenote: I know it is redundant to have 2 indexes with same prefix. These are just tryouts, and I happened to see the sizes of the 2 indexes.

Do you know what might be possible causes for this? I expected the opposite to happen.

It is not a matter of indexes still building in the background, as I've waited long enough, and the collection is only ~5million records.

I am using `MongoDB 4.2.6 Community`

Comment: While I dont have info about the size, having two indexes with same **index prefix** is not required - its redundant. Your application will do just fine with just the compound  index (index on two fields) only. Moreover indexes on array fields occupy more memory.

Comment: You are right, they are redundant indeed. I don't plan on keeping them both, but I am trying out some queries, and while tryouts are in progress, I am keeping them both.